Data structures for compiled XPath queries
What kind of data structures are usually utilized for compiled XPath queries? Is it just AST or something else? If so, how is the search in DOM usually implemented? Is it just depth-first search traversing in DOM using parts of the query AST?

It's going to vary considerably from one processor to another. Some may be pure interpreters, some compile down to Java bytecode or similar. There are plenty of open source processors, I suggest you study them.
A processor will typically start by building a syntax tree, then do various semantic checks e.g. that variables are declared, then do some kind of decorating of the tree (for example, adding information derived from static type inferencing), then do various tree-rewriting optimisations such as constant folding (pre-evaluation of constant subexpressions) or loop-lifting, then use an interpreter pattern to evaluate the result.
The faster processors don't search DOM directly, they build an indexed representation of the tree that is more efficient for searching and navigation.

Can you always do constant folding "on-the-fly", and/or does it pay off to do it as a separate step?

Doing it thoroughly requires multiple passes, for example if you have an expression like $x + 1 where $x turns out to have a value that can be statically evaluated. How much optimization "pays off" depends on how often the code is executed; that's why there is a move these days to just-in-time optimization that's done during execution based on actual execution metrics.
